# $f'(z)$ is imaginary on the complex axis

Tags: complex-analysis

A question from [Bak-Newman](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441972870). Suppose $f(z)$ is real-valued and differentiable for all imaginary points $z$. Show that $f'(z)$ is imaginary at all imaginary points $z$.

First, is there a standard symbol for the set of imaginary points $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: z = iy, y \in \mathbb{R}\}$?

Second, is the following proof legit?  Edited to address some sloppiness on my part (thanks to comments). Let $y \in \mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary. Then $iy$ is an arbitrary point on the complex axis. By the definition of the derivative we have

\begin{equation}
  f'(iy) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(iy+h) - f(iy)}{h}
\end{equation}
where $h \in \mathbb{C}$. However, if the derivative exists it is the same no matter the manner in which $h \to 0$. In particular if we restrict $h$ to be purely imaginary the above equality still holds. In fact, letting $h = ir$, $r \in \mathbb{R}$ we get

\begin{equation}
  f'(iy) = \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{f(i(y+r)) - f(iy)}{ir} = \frac{1}{i} \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(i(y+r)) - f(y)}{r}
\end{equation}
and $f(iy)$ and $f(i(y+r))$ are real by assumption. Hence the derivative is imaginary.

Comment: First, when you pull the $i$ out in front of the limit, it is $\frac{1}{i}$.  Second, $y$ is not imaginary.  You state that $y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a standard symbol for the imaginary line.  Perhaps $i \mathbb{R}$ (I think I've seen $e^{i\theta}\mathbb{R}$ used for a line at angle $\theta$).

Your proof is along the right lines, but the details are wrong; you may have just made some mistakes in typing it out.  Let $y$ and $h$ be real, and consider
$$
f'(iy) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(iy+ih) - f(iy)}{ih} ~.
$$

Answer (score 0):

If we use this fact $f(z) = f(x+iy) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$. If $f(z)$ is real valued then it must be of the form $f(z) = u(x,y)$. Then:

$$f'(iy) = \lim_{h\to 0} = \frac{u(x, y+h) - u(x,y)}{ih} = -i \lim_{h\to 0} = \frac{u(x, y+h) - u(x,y)}{h}$$

This limit resembles the definition of a partial derivative of a real function.